# Is cofactor matrix of 2x2 matrices unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Please consider the 2x2 matrix below:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{array}\right]$

According to the definition given [here](https://semath.info/src/cofactor-matrix.html) and [here](https://www.teachoo.com/9780/1204/Minor-and-Cofactor-of-a-determinant/category/Finding-Minors-and-cofactors/), the cofactor matrix becomes:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} a_{22} & -a_{12} \\ -a_{21} & a_{11} \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 4 & -2 \\ -3 & 1\end{array}\right]$

However, when I follow the practice given [here](https://www.mathstips.com/co-factor-of-matrices/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6528024/3393574), I do obtain the following cofactor matrix, which is the transpose of the above:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} a_{22} & -a_{21} \\ -a_{12} & a_{11} \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 4 & -3 \\ -2 & 1\end{array}\right]$

The difference arises from the off-diagonal locations of $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$.

Are these two cofactors equivalent to each other in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first "here" link is wrong. The second one, contrary to your thinking, gives the correct interpretation.

The rule is simple: to obtain the minor/cofactor of any element, strike out the whole row and column that contain it. Hence it cannot contain the element self.

Comment: Exactly. What the first link calls the cofactor matrix is actually the adjugate matrix.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I guess that there are other anomalies on that page.